# Oauth2 Instagram API "redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, omniauth, instagram

I am working on a Rails application which is in development mode and it can register with omniauth.

The host is

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

I'm using the gems:

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-foursquare'
gem 'omniauth-instagram'
```

When I register through omniauth with Foursquare there's no problem at all. All the settings are right and my redirect_uri in the Foursquare developer settings equals to the host (localhost:3000)

However, if I fill in the exact same redirect_uri (localhost:3000) in the Instagram client manager*. Instagram gives me this:

```
{
 "code": 400,
 "error_type": "OAuthException",
 "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered             redirect URI"
}
```

Based upon this URL:

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<ID>&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Finstagram%2Fcallback&state=18415adf24dd97873e61094f67c0fb7a94857fedf93e9d2e&scope=basic
```

*
[image]

What am I doing wrong according to Instagram and how should this be fixed?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Fixed the issue myself. Added `localhost:3000/auth/instagram/callback` as redirect_uri and it worked just fine.

Comment: I had to add /users/auth/instagram/callback

Comment: Try without the port, I setup an actual route in my node app and ended up setting it to http://localhost/instagram/callback, and that returned the result.

Answer (score 9):

When you specify a redirect URI http://localhost:3000 is not the same as http://localhost:3000/ (note the trailing slash).

Make sure the callback URI matches exactly.

Answer (score 8):

I needed to add

```
http://localhost:3000/users/auth/instagram/callback
```

as my callback URI because I'm using Devise.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupagram module (Drupal 7) added: `http://localhost:3000/instagram/oauth` as redirect_uri

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is having this issue and the redirect uri provided to instagram is exactly the same as the one you're using, i've found that some users were typing my website address as `http://www.example.com/login` when in my instagram api it was `http://example.com/login`.

Then I created a php script to detect if the string `www` exists in my url and then reload to the same page but without the `www`.

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'www.') !== FALSE) {
    header("Location: ".str_replace('www.', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue: Oauth2 Instagram API “redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI

My Solution: Please check ng-cordova-oauth.js file and check instagram function in that. Verify redirect_uri value is same as register your application on developer console for Instagram.If it is same it works properly,otherwise you get the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"}

How to get Access token from instagram

Your website url must be same when registering sandbox clien api on instagram https://www.instagram.com/developer/

here we used website url: https://adlivetech.com
Valid redirect URIs:      https://adlivetech.com/

For live website you can get Access token easily by using https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token

Replace above url  "CLIENT-ID" with your client ID
Replace above url "REDIRECT-URI" redirect url should be your domain name like: http://adlivetech.com

https://adlivetech.com/access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOken

Answer (score 0):

I mucked around with this for ages..
perhaps it has changed but: 
http://localhost:3000/users/auth/instagram/int_callback 
was the callback URI that finally worked for me.
The ONLY issue i was having was that it was exactly an incorrect callback uri and wish I had seen here that I should be focusing on my Instagram setup instead of modifying my code.. to get the error message means everything else is working (so far), otherwise you would not be getting that particular error message.
Good luck!! - don't get distracted!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a ruby-specific but for anyone else wrestling w/this here's what got me past it (note: nothing in above answers worked for me):

- `1. Edit your Client on Instagram Developer and uncheck Disable implicit OAuth.`
- `2. Click Update Client to save it.`
- `3. Now go to https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&redirect_ur.... Just change [CLIENT_ID] and [REDIRECT_URI] with their values.`
- `4. After that you will be redirected to [REDIRECT_URI]/#access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]. Get it and place it on the Instagram Access Token textbox.`

(Source: https://www.drupal.org/project/instagram_feeds/issues/2140479)

Comment: will you please elaborate 4th point.. I have completed upto 3rd point

Answer (score -1):

...Or you can follow the instructions here:

https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/?hl=en

See "Step One: Direct your user to our authorization URL" section.

Just simply supply your CLIENT_ID and REDIRECT_URI.

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code
```