# {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, instagram, instagram-api

This will probably be a really dumb question but I'm pretty new to this and am trying to learn how to use the Instagram API for Ruby.

I installed Sinatra and am trying to go to localhost:4567 to run the sample application found here: [Instagram API Sample Application](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem). I replaced the CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET in the code in the link with my actual client ID and secret.

My website URL is set to http://localhost:4567/ and redirect URI is also set to the same link.

This is probably a really dumb issue and really easy to fix--could someone please help me? Below is the error message I got.

```
{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered             redirect URI"}
```

Comment: Seems like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537721/oauth2-instagram-api-redirect-uri-does-not-match-registered-redirect-uri) is described solution of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are not reading the error message right.

You don't have to set the website URL and redirect URL same, rather u have to make sure that the redirect URL you set is same as the `redirect_uri` url param you pass to authenticate in oauth2 step.