# Login as Pinterest in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web, asp.net-web-api, pinterest

How can I integrate Pinterest api with asp.net. I have a pinterest button in my project, when I will click on it the pinterest login window should show in a new window for logging through pinterest user id and password.
Please suggest important links/codes...

Comment: you might want to take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455388/how-to-get-oauth-access-token-for-pinterest

Comment: "status": "failure", "code": 7, "host": "coreapp-ngapi-prod-964e6629", "generated_at": "Thu, 29 Oct 2015 07:47:31 +0000", "message": "You are not permitted to access that resource.", "data": "The provided redirect_uri does not match any of the registered redirect URIs."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537721/oauth2-instagram-api-redirect-uri-does-not-match-registered-redirect-uri