# Can't Connect to Instagram through omniauth Rails

Tags: instagram

I am getting the following error with try to connect Instagram app using omniauth rails gem. What's going wrong please tell me.

{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"}

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue myself and spent a good 2 days on it. Make sure to take a look at the solutions suggested here first; [Oauth2 Instagram API "redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537721/oauth2-instagram-api-redirect-uri-does-not-match-registered-redirect-uri).

If your issue is not this; there is a recent bug introduced with the gem 'omnioauth-oauth2' 1.4.0 so you need to downgrade to 1.3.1.

In your **gemfile.lock file** (not list), change the omnioauth-oauth2 **version to 1.3.1** from 1.4.0. Then on the command line enter **bundle update 'omniauth-oauth2'**. This solved the issue for me.

If you get the same error; additionally include gem 'omniauth-oauth2', '~> 1.3.1' in your gem file and do 'bundle update'.